# Custom SessionState module for .NET - Capturing errors

Tags: .net, session

We use a custom session state server on our web site (SessionStateServer).  Every once in a while it totally bombs out.  We try to redirect to an error page, but the application tries to AquireState, which makes a call to the state server which causes another error.  Is there any place in the application or page lifecycle where we could catch the error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can capture the error in your custom session state server!

Do proper exception handling and you won't have this problem. Catch exceptions at the top level of your module and log them to the event log or somewhere else. A custom error page is not helpful to your Operations staff in solving the problem.